# Generically call static methods

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, static

I currently have two (core) classes :

```
public abstract class BO<TConfig> where TConfig : BOConfigBase
{
    protected TConfig Config { get; set; }
    internal List<BC> _BCs { get; set; }

    public abstract void Init();

    public void Process() => _BCs.ForEach(bc => bc.Process());
}

public class BOOne : BO<BOConfigOne>
{
    public BOOne(BOConfigOne config)
    {
        Config = config;
    }

    public override void Init()
    {
        _BCs = new List<BC>()
        {
            BCA.Init(Config),
            BCB.Init(Config),
            BCC.Init(Config),
            BCOneA.Init(Config)
        };
    }
}
```

Then the code for my BCs

```
public abstract class BC
{
    protected BOConfigBase Config { get; set; }
    public abstract void Process();
}

public class BCA : BC
{
    private BCA()
    {
    }

    public static BCA Init(BOConfigBase config)
    {
        BCA ret = new BCA { Config = config };
        return ret;
    }

    public override void Process()
    {
        Config.Counter += 1;
    }
}
```

To call this, I will do this :

```
    static void Main()
    {
        {
            var boConfigOne = new BOConfigOne()
            {
                A = "one",
                B = "one",
                C = "one",
                One = "one"
            };
            var testBO = new BOOne(boConfigOne);
            testBO.Init();
            testBO.Process();
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"A = {boConfigOne.A}, B = {boConfigOne.B}, C = {boConfigOne.C}, One = {boConfigOne.One}, Counter = {boConfigOne.Counter}");
        }

        {
            var boConfigTwo = new BOConfigTwo()
            {
                A = "two",
                B = "two",
                C = "two",
                Two = "two"
            };

            var testBOTwo = new BOTwo(boConfigTwo);
            testBOTwo.Init();
            testBOTwo.Process();
            Console.WriteLine(
                $"A = {boConfigTwo.A}, B = {boConfigTwo.B}, C = {boConfigTwo.C}, Two = {boConfigTwo.Two}, Counter = {boConfigTwo.Counter}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

BO stands for Business Orchestration, and BC for Business Component. A BC would perform a single function, and a BO would contain several of these re-usable BCs.

I would like to change the BO to be able to Init all the BCs generically, something like `Init => BCs.Foreach(bc => bc.Init(Config));`. The problem is that my BC's Init's are static, hence I can't put it in an interface, and call it on the interface, nor can I put it in the base abstract method, and override it.

Does anyone have a better solution for me?

Comment: We can help you (better) and review the code when you show us your real implementation. This looks very much like pseudocode or hypothetical one.

Comment: @t3chb0t. This is the current working set of code I have as a POC. If I can get this to work, I will then implement it completely. I'll add the basic call of the methods to show the test implementation of it as well.

Comment: This is a very good idea. Could you tell us at least what BCA, BO etc stand for so we have some more context?

Comment: @t3chb0t, my apologies. So used to use the terms in my environment, I forgot to add. BC stands for Business Component, BO stands for Business Orchestration. So, a BO would contain several (reusable in other BO) BC's, that would perform a single function, like updating the DB, writing a file, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest it's hard to follow with such abstract class names and POC.  The root of what you are describing is you have a factory method to create one of your classes.  Lucky for you it seems all the factory methods have the same method signature.  We can make this a bit easier.

Need to store the factory methods in a private field to be used by the Init method.  Also adding a "helper" method to make storing the factories easier.

```
public abstract class BO<TConfig> where TConfig : BOConfigBase
{
    protected TConfig Config { get; set; }
    internal List<BC> _BCs { get; set; }
    private Func<BOConfigBase, BC>[] _factories = new Func<BOConfigBase, BC>[0];

    protected void SetFactories(params Func<BOConfigBase, BC>[] factories)
    {
        _factories = factories;
    }

    public void Init()
    {
        _BCs = _factories.Select(b => b(Config)).ToList();
    }

    public void Process() => _BCs.ForEach(bc => bc.Process());
}
```

Now BOOne class can call it like

```
public class BOOne : BO<BOConfigOne>
{
    public BOOne(BOConfigOne config)
    {
        Config = config;
        SetFactories(BCA.Init, BCB.Init, BCC.Init, BCOneA.Init);
    }
}
```

I'm assuming each BO class would take different BC classes if not then you could constructer inject all the factories.